# How to connect the audio to a separate speaker?

Tags: xbox-one, audio-hardware

I'm trying to figure out how to get the audio from Live TV to a separate speaker.  I've got the HDMI-out from the Xbox going to a projector instead of a TV and the projector's built-in audio sucks.  I've got a [decent bluetooth speaker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I053ICY) with a 3.5 mm audio-in jack that I'd like to use. The Xbox has an "IR".

So I'm wondering, can I get both audio/video in through the HDMI and send the video out to the projector and the audio out to the speaker's audio-in jack?

**Edit**: sounds like some pics may help.

**Xbox: [Xbox One S 500GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01L1Y0TCC)**
[image]

**Speaker: [Sony SRSX5 Portable NFC Bluetooth Wireless Speaker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I053ICY)**

[image]

**Projector: [Viewsonic PJD5255](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SFJ9MR0)**

- does not have bluetooth
- the projector is mounted on the ceiling so it would be nicer to run an audio cable from the Xbox rather than from the projector's RCA outputs

[image]

Comment: FWIW, [this converter on amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Converter-Optical-TOSLink-Coaxial/dp/B00BVT4M30/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?s=aht&ie=UTF8&qid=1483138214&sr=1-1-fkmr1&keywords=FIIO+D3+%28D03K%29+Digital+to+Analog+Audio+Converter) comes with both the optical cable & the analog cable - the full package for $24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [optical to analog converter](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Fosmon-Digital-Coaxial-Optical-SPDIF-Toslink-to-Analog-L-R-3.5mm-Jack-Audio-Converter-comes-with-AC-Adapter/41291763) to take the optical audio from the xbox to the speaker.

[image]

You would most likely *also* get audio out of the projector due to the HDMI, and you'd have to turn down the projector volume down manually.

Comment: Ok, yeah this sounds right.  I'm not familiar with the spdif port, but it looks like the cable you're showing here does _not_ connect to a 3.5mm port directly, is that right?  I'm still trying to figure out what I need to go from spdif to 3.5mm analog.

Comment: I'm looking over the page and I think this is designed to go from spdif to 3.5mm _digital_ audio.  From that site: "This cable is designed to connect a digital audio device with a Toslink jack to a digital audio device with a Mini-Toslink jack."  My speakers only have the 3.5mm _analog_ jack, so I don't think these would work.

Comment: Looking around further, it appears you can't go from optical digital audio to analog audio with just a cable (which kind of makes sense).  It appears that something like [this converter](https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Converter-Optical-TOSLink-Coaxial/dp/B00BVT4M30/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?s=aht&ie=UTF8&qid=1483138214&sr=1-1-fkmr1&keywords=FIIO+D3+%28D03K%29+Digital+to+Analog+Audio+Converter) would work.

Comment: Indeed, just updated with a similar device, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Some newer projectors will have bluetooth connection as an available audio/out, try its settings.

Or if the Xbox straight up has a 3.5mm connection in the back.

Or if the Xbox has different audio out options.

Comment: No bluetooth on the projector & xboxes don't have a 3.5mm port.